# Совместное использование friendly_id и acts_as_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте!

Возник вопрос при совместном использовании двух этих гемов в модели Category (категории объявлений). С помощью acts_as_nested_set формируется древовидная структура категорий, а с помощью friendly_id дружественные URL. При этом возможно появление веток дерева с одинаковым названием (title). Код модели категорий сейчас выглядит следующим образом:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  acts_as_nested_set

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug, :title, scope: [:site_id, :parent_id]

  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders, :scoped], scope: [:site_id]

  private

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed?
  end

end
```

Структура категорий такая:

```
Недвижимость
  Продаю  (slug: prodayu )
Автомобили
  Продаю  (slug: prodayu-91722faf-13e5-40b2-8685-da5a34fe59fa)
```

Для уникальности frendly_id добавляет UUID.

Как избавится от появления UUIDов в slug для категорий под разными родительскими категориями с не уникальными title?

Comment: А при чём тут nested set, позвольте спросить?

Comment: Позволяю  :) Gem https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set позволяет стоить категории в виде дерева. В моем приложении возможно появление веток дерева с одинаковым названием. 
В коде модельки уникальность названия категории определяется вот так validates_uniqueness_of :slug, :title, scope: [:site_id, :parent_id]

Надеюсь теперь стало понятней?

Comment: Только непонятно за что минус? Понять вопрос не смогли или не хватает знаний дать ответ?

Comment: Нет, не стало. В вопросе нет упоминаний NS. UUID прилетели от friendly_id, а NS вопрос не касается. Если это два вопроса в одном, то хотя бы сформулируйте их оба конкретно, а не "кто и как ее решал", т.к. в разных ситуациях разные решения. PS: минус не мой, но вопрос и правда так себе. Но вы можете его привести в порядок! Тогда минусы могут быть отозваны или хотя бы перекрыты.

Comment: Вы внутри вопроса, по-моему, зарыли мысль о том, что хотите **разрешить** одинаковые slug'и, если они под разными родительскими категориями. Это объясняет, при чём здесь NS. Это догадка. Если я прав, укажите в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в модель Category публичный метод titles для формирования строки из заголовков всех родительских категорий + заголовок объекта.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  include TheSortableTree::Scopes
  extend FriendlyId

  acts_as_nested_set
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug, :title, scope: [:site_id, :parent_id]

  friendly_id :titles, use: [:slugged, :finders, :scoped], scope: [:site_id]

  def titles
    self_and_ancestors.map(&:title).join(" ")
  end

  private

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed? or parent_id_changed?
  end

end
```

Решить задачу с помощью callback'ов на уровне моделей не удалось. Пришлось использовать действия внутри контроллера. Для этого, внес изменения в три действия контроллера:

- create - При создании объекта стандартные callback friendly_id при вызове кода self_and_ancestors.map(&:title).join(" ") не отрабатывают. После успешного сохранения объекта @category.save выполняется обновление slug в действии create контроллера @category.update_attribute(:slug, @category.titles.parameterize).
- update - При обновлении объекта так-же, не срабатывает указанный выше код через callback модели. После действия выполняется метод rebuild_slug.
- rebuild - При использовании gem [the_sortable_tree](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_sortable_tree), если меняется структура каталога обновление slug всех подчиненных категорий после действия rebuild. После действия выполняется метод rebuild_slug.

После изменений, контроллер приобрел следующий вид:

```
class Manage::CategoriesController < ManageController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :rebuild, :destroy]
  after_action :rebuild_slug, only: [:update, :rebuild]

  include TheSortableTreeController::Rebuild

  ...

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    @category.site_id = current_site_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        @category.update_attribute(:slug, @category.titles.parameterize)
        format.html { redirect_to manage_categories_path, notice: 'Категория объявлений создана.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  ...

  private

  def rebuild_slug
    @category.self_and_descendants.each { |c| c.update_attribute(:slug, c.titles.parameterize) }
  end

  ...

end
```

В итоге формируется категории со следующей структурой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение неидеально, но работает. Хотелось бы все это реализовать с помощью callback модели. Остается надежда на то, что Сообщество поможет...